# Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can a pair of groups be embedded in each other?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62667/when-can-a-pair-of-groups-be-embedded-in-each-other)

Let $G,H$ be two groups. Let $f:G\rightarrow H$, $g:H\rightarrow G$ be injective group homomorphisms. From the  Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, it follows that the underlying sets of $G,H$ are equipotent.  Does it follow that $G,H$ are isomorphic ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No. Consider $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}C_4$ and $C_2\times\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}C_4$.

Comment: @DonAntonio What is the isomorphism

Comment: I think DonAntonio assumed the groups to be finite. Nonabelian free groups of different ranks are a further standard example.

Comment: This question seems to be essentially a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62667/49437

Comment: Oops! I read "injective and surjective"...my bad.

Comment: @Martin OK. yes it is a duplicate