# Are homomorphisms antisymmetric?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering whether the antisymmetry of cardinality (expressed in the Shroeder-Bernstein Theorem) carries over to homomorphisms. That is, if A and B are algebraic structures of the same type, and there is an injective homomorphism from A to B, and there is an injective homomorphism from B to A, then are A and B necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259081/if-there-are-injective-homomorphisms-between-two-groups-in-both-directions-are

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I appreciate the feedback.