# Isomorphism between two factor groups, where group $G$ consists of all the numbers with magnitude 1

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of complex numbers of modulus $1$ and $G_n$ is the subgroup of $G$ consisting of the $n$-th roots of unity. For $m,n \in \mathbb N$, show that $G/G_n$ and $G/G_m$ are isomorphic.

---

My approach.

Let us define a function $\phi_n $ : $ G \to G$, such that   $\phi_n $($g_1$) $ =g_1^n$, $ \forall g_1 \in G$.

Clearly $G_n$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi_n $. Let us say $H_n , H_m$ are the range of $\phi_n $ and $\phi_m $ respectively.

Now let us define another function $ \pi $ : $H_n \to H_m$, such that $h_i \mapsto h_i$. Now essentially for all $h_i$, there exist atleast one $g_i$ such that $g_i^n=h_i$.

Now ofcourse $\forall $ $g_i \in G$,     $g_i^{\frac{n}{m}}$ $\in G$, as both of them are of unit magnitude. This implies $\forall $ $g_i \in G$, $g_i^n \in G/G_m$.

This implies the function $\pi$ is valid and of course one-one.

Interchanging the role of $ m$ and $n$, we can say there exists an one-one function between $H_m$ and $H_n$ as well.

So, $H_n$ and $H_m$ are isomorphic groups, so of course $G/G_n$ is isomorphic to  $G/G_m$  .

Is it all right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $G\simeq\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ via the exponential map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb C:x\mapsto e^{ix}$.

Via the same map you have $G/G_n\simeq \Bbb R/\frac{2\pi}{n}\Bbb Z$.

Finally, the map $\Bbb R/\frac{2\pi}{n}\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R/ 2\pi\Bbb Z: x\mapsto nx$ is an isomorphism.

Therefore $G/G_n\simeq G$ independently of $n$.

---

Notes about your own proof:

- note that $H_n$ and $H_m$ are both $G$ itself since $\phi_n$ is surjective for all $n$ (every unit complex number has a unit $n$-th root). Therefore $\pi$ is the identity map $G\to G$. I'm not sure you're going anywhere with this map.
- what is the purpose of the subscripts $1$ in $g_1$ and $i$ in $g_i$? (as far as I can see there is none and you can drop them)
- what is the meaning of $g^{\frac nm}$ when $g\in G$? Any unit complex number has $m$ $m$-th roots.
- when you say

> "This implies $\forall $ $g_i \in G$, $g_i^n \in G/G_m$."

That doesn't make sense. If $g\in G$, you *can* consider the class of $g_i^n$ in the quotient $G/G_m$, but it doesn't intrinsically live there!

- the existence of an injective function $H_n\to H_m$ and another injective map $H_m\to H_n$ [is not a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259081/if-there-are-injective-homomorphisms-between-two-groups-in-both-directions-are) that $H_n$ and $H_m$ are isomorphic. What you need to find is **one** map that is bijective and such that both the map and its inverse are homomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, I understood your argument but can you please tell me whether my method is right or not?

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury I was in the process of editing my answer. Done now.

Comment: Well, I have something to say about your last paragraph. I mean suppose there exists $f_1: A \to B$ and $f_2 : B \to A$ where both are injective. Of course range($f_1$) is isomorphic to $A$ and range($f_2$) is isomorphic to $B$. This implies $A$ contains an isomorphic copy of $B$, and $B$ contains an isomorphic copy of $A$; These are true together iff $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic to each other. This is how I deduced it. Although it is very much possible that I am missing something.  @Arnaud Mortier

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury This might very well be true, but then you need a reference or a proof, and you also need to state that you are using that, because it is neither obvious nor classic.

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury It is, in fact, wrong: see edit.