# Is there a nice 'local' criterion for equivalence of categories?

Tags: category-theory

A first tentative guess would be <s>"two categories $A$ and $B$ are equivalent iff each connected component of $A$ is equivalent to a (full) subcategory of $B$ and vice versa", but this fails, for example, in the case of $FiniteFields$ and $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$</s> [wrong]

Trying to strengthen it to "[...] iff each connected component of $A$ is ('strictly') isomorphic to some subcategory of $B$, and vice versa" then fails (in the other direction) for 'smaller' skeletons

A somewhat compromising possibility, involving a 'global' condition, (which I'm not sure actually holds; please tell if it's false, or well-known) would be a Dedekind-Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein-type proposition: "two categories are equivalent iff for one of them, every connected component is equivalent to some subcategory of the other, *and, on the opposite direction,* there is a fully faithful (not necessarily essentially surjective) functor"

Comment: I don’t understand the first paragraph. **FiniteFields** and $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ are not equivalent, but neither is it true that every connected component of **FiniteFields** is equivalent to a subcategory of $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $(\mathbb N, \mid)$ where "$\mid$" means "divides" (not sure the notation is completely standard)?

Comment: @krm2233 Even then, it doesn’t work. The field of four elements has two automorphisms, but no element of a poset, considered as a category, does.

Comment: @JeremyRickard you're right

Comment: @krm2233 i was really the usual order

Comment: possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372047/746936

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be the disjoint union of countably many copies of the category $\bullet\to\bullet$, and let $B$ be the disjoint union of $A$ with the category $\bullet$. Then $A$ and $B$ are not equivalent, but there are fully faithful functors in both directions, and each connected component of either is equivalent to a subcategory of the other.

Comment: so even with more global information from both directions, it fails, good to know